# display a blurred shape on a map instead of the real address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, bing-maps, mappy

I have a website and I would like to display the user address on a map (using google map or not), but I don't want to display the exact address. I would to have something like a blurred shape (or a cloud) or something like that.
I want only to point the location, the area of where the address is situated.

Is it possible to display a coloured line over the street where the exact address is ?
Here is a itinerary :

[https://maps.google.fr/maps?saddr=Bd+Haussmann&daddr=Bd+Haussmann,+Paris&hl=fr&sll=48.873811,2.327992&sspn=0.006273,0.013937&geocode=FcTB6QIdTX4jAA%3BFXHD6QIdHHEjACnt0p46y2_mRzElMYVUFdBUPg&oq=bd+haus&mra=dme&mrsp=0&sz=17&t=m&z=17](https://maps.google.fr/maps?saddr=Bd%20Haussmann&daddr=Bd%20Haussmann,%20Paris&hl=fr&sll=48.873811,2.327992&sspn=0.006273,0.013937&geocode=FcTB6QIdTX4jAA;FXHD6QIdHHEjACnt0p46y2_mRzElMYVUFdBUPg&oq=bd%20haus&mra=dme&mrsp=0&sz=17&t=m&z=17)

Is possible to have draw a line like in the example if a have the exact address (which is between point A and poitn B)

Does anybody know how to do something like that ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: Using Lng, Lat(Longitude/ Latitude) you can do that, refer Google Documentation for that, and if you want help with your code Please paste some of your code..

Comment: Hi, thanks. The code I don't have it yet, I'm just at the beginning. But I would like to display next to the user name, picture a small map with his aproximative location

Comment: Then like you said just display a small map, but don't put any marking or indications on it denoting exactly where the user is.

Comment: Make thing clear you want to point user address or user's home road, both are different thing, yes it is possible.

Comment: User address, but not showing it. So I was thinking to draw a line on the street where the address is so, I will show the street but not the number.